# angular js Unit test for directive jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have written angular js directive one method, but I don't know how to write unit test for that.

```
 var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

 app.directive('minMax', function() {

    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, mCtrl) {
            function myValidation(value) {
                if (value.toString().length > 2 & value.toString().length < 6) {
                    mCtrl.$setValidity('charE', true);
                } else {
                    mCtrl.$setValidity('charE', false);
                }
                return value;
            }
            mCtrl.$parsers.push(myValidation);
        }
    };
});
```

How do I test this method?

Comment: <form name="myForm">
 <p>Pin Code:
  <input type="number" name="pincode" ng-model="pincode" required min-max> 
   <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.pincode.$dirty && myForm.pincode.$invalid">Minimum 3 to Maximum 6</span>
  </p>
</form>

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: https://github.com/daniellmb/angular-test-patterns.
It contains a great collection of test patterns.

Example of directive test:

```
describe('Directive: myDir', function () {
  var element, scope, compile, defaultData,
      validTemplate = '<my-dir ng-model="data"></my-dir>';

  function createDirective(data, template) {
    var elm;

    // Setup scope state
    scope.data = data || defaultData;

    // Create directive
    elm = compile(template || validTemplate)(scope);

    // Trigger watchers
    //scope.$apply();

    // Return
    return elm;
  }

  beforeEach(function () {

    // Load the directive's module
    module('myApp');

    // Reset data each time
    defaultData = 42;

    // Provide any mocks needed
    module(function ($provide) {
      //$provide.value('Name', new MockName());
    });

    // Inject in angular constructs otherwise,
    //  you would need to inject these into each test
    inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      compile = $compile;
    });
  });

  describe('when created', function () {
    // Add specs
  });

  describe('when the model changes', function () {
    // Add specs
  });

  describe('when destroyed', function () {
    // Add specs
  });
});
```